# Destructors and the delete() method in C++

Tags: c++, heap-memory, destructor

So I added a destructor function to a class in C++.

```
class object { ~object() };
```

And declared an object with the new method, thereby allocating it on the heap

```
object *pointer = new object;
```

Do I still need to use the

```
delete(object);
```

method at the end of the program? (Isn't the destructor already responsible for exactly this?)

Comment: Yes, in this case, you still need to call `delete` in order to call the destructor and deallocate the memory.

Comment: Or `std::unique_ptr<object> pointer(new object());` and stop letting naked pointers own resources.

Comment: And, as new, delete doesn't need parenthesis..

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need to use a pointer and `new` in the first place.

Comment: The destructor is responsible for destroying the object. It is not responsible for deciding when the object gets destroyed. There's a big difference between the two concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You still must call `delete(object)`. Destructor is responsible for how to delete an object and `delete(object)` is responsible for when to delete it. But in modern C++ usage of naked pointers is considered a really bad practice. You should consider using smart pointers, such as std::unique_ptr for managing memory.

Comment: what's a "naked pointer"?

Comment: @CaioV. A naked pointer is just a plain pointer. For example `X*` is a naked pointer (no memory management) and `shared_ptr<X>` is a smart pointer (deletes the referenced object if it is no longer used)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different kinds of memory. The **stack** and the **heap**.

Everything on the stack deletes itself when you go out of scope (one of the steps of deletion is calling the destructor)

Everything which is on the heap (you call `malloc`, `new`, etc) you have to delete explicitly by yourself (which will then result in the destructor being called).

Smart pointers like `unique_ptr` / `shared_ptr` are a modern c++ way to get rid of the manual deletion on heap objects and to make sure they get deleted when the objects are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors are a way of customizing the clean-up process (add logging, provide cleanup as per rule of three/five, etc.). You still need to `delete`, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

That being said, it's frowned-upon and considered a bad practice to write code that actially *needs* `new`s and `delete`s (especially the latter). If you need to store an object on the heap, use `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` or a container like `vector`.

If you have the time, I suggest you watch Herb Sutter's talk  from C++Con 2016: [Leak-Freedom in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor gets called when the objects lifetime is over. For heap allocated objects this means when you delete them.
So a call to

```
delete(object);
```

calls your descructor and frees the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must need `Delete` method.

`Default destructors` call destructors of member `objects`, but do `NOT` delete **pointers to objects**. Thus, You need to write destructors that **explicitly call delete**. Like,

```
delete pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I still need to use the `delete(object);` method at the end of the program?

Yes.

> Isn't the destructor already responsible for exactly this?

No.

Your `delete ptr;` is what *invokes* that destructor. If you hadn't declared a destructor, one would have been declared for you, so that made no difference.

You don't need to write `delete ptr;` when your object has automatic storage duration (very loosely: "when you didn't create it with `new`"), because then the equivalent is done for you.

But in both cases the destructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

A new and a delete expression (which are not the new and delete operators) are invoking two calls:

new:

```
1) call the operator new for memory allocation
2) invoke the appropriate constructor
```

delete:

```
1) invoke the destructor
2) call the operator delete for memory deallocation
```

Hence you have to pair any new with a delete, to avoid resource (memory) leaks.
However, object construction and destruction does not require new and delete.